# Помогите с тг ботом на python, проблема с клавиатурой

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, google-translate

Решил написать telegram-бота на python - гугл-переводчик, который использует библиотеку googletrans. После нажатия кнопки "старт" в самом тг код ломается и выдает ошибку
код:

```
import config as cfg
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
a = 0
keyss = []
keyb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
for i, j in cfg.LANGDICT.items():
    key = InlineKeyboardButton(j, callback_data=i)
    keyss.append(key)
    a+= 1;
    if a == 3:
        a = 0
        keyb.add(keyss[0], keyss[1], keyss[2])
        keyss = []
```

Ошибка:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\333\Desktop\TraslatorBot-main\TraslatorBot-main\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import keyboard as k
  File "C:\Users\333\Desktop\TraslatorBot-main\TraslatorBot-main\keyboard.py", line 7, in <module>
    keyb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 164, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardMarkup
inline_keyboard
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
Process finished with exit code 1**
```

помогите, пожалуйста! остальное могу скинуть, если понадобится

Comment: Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict] где у тебя параметры в функции?